# GNUplot doesn't print lines

Tags: gnuplot

I'm having this script to plot some data in Gnuplot. Unfortunately, my plot doesn't print the lines, only the dots.

What have I done wrong?

```
#!/usr/bin/gnuplot
reset
set terminal png
set output 'picture.png'
set xlabel "n"

set ylabel "time (s)"
set yrange [0:2]

set title "title"
set key reverse Left outside
set grid
set style data linespoints

plot "bla.txt" using 1:2 title "bla" with linespoints ls 1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most probably, your data file contains empty lines between successive data entries.

A data file with

```
1 2

2 4

5 6
```

shows only three points when plotted with

```
plot 'data.txt' using 1:2 with linespoints
```

whereas a data file

```
1 2
3 4
5 6
```

also shows connecting lines.

That is simply how gnuplot handles its data files.